# Implicit conversion from char** to const char**

Tags: c++, c, string, gcc, casting

Why my compiler(GCC) doesnt implicitly cast from `char**` to `const char**`?

Thie following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(const char** thing) {
    std::cout << thing[0] << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    print(argv);
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
oi.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
oi.cpp:8:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’ [-fpermissive]
oi.cpp:3:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void print(const char**)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: [Why am I getting an error converting a `Foo**` → `Foo const**`?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17)

Comment: There is no such thing as an "implicit cast".  A `cast` is an explicit operator that specifies a conversion.  There can also be implicit conversions.  ("cast" is the operator, "conversion" is the operation.)

Comment: @Keith: I think that terminology is not a problem. After all, we say "up-cast" and not "up-conversion". Or, at least, I say that. :-)

Comment: @André: it isn't; `Foo**` and `const Foo*` differ in the number of levels of indirection.  You *can* convert from `Foo*` to `const Foo*`, because that conversion doesn't make it possible to modify a read-only object; you're just taking a pointer to a read-write object and promising not to modify it.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2009/12/a-question-on-indirect-constness/

Comment: Note: I have added `c` tag in because the gist of the problem is the same in both languages (no point having two separate threads IMHO), although the solution suggested by Alf only works in C++ unfortunately. In C you're stuck with an ugly cast.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Such a conversion would allow you to put a `const char*` into your array of `char*`, which would be unsafe. In `print` you could do:

```
thing[0] = "abc";
```

Now `argv[0]` would point to a string literal that cannot be modified, while `main` expects it to be non-const (`char*`). So for type safety this conversion is not allowed.

Comment: Very nice explanation I didn't think of it this way, thanks. Changing it to `char *const *thing` works as expected. However then also `const char *const *thing` should work, but doesn't. I'd be greatful for any more info on that.

Comment: So it works for C++ but doesn't for C, so I posted new question for that because I can't find any answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319842/why-c-doesnt-allow-implicit-conversion-from-char-to-const-char-const-and

Answer (score 6):

@Fred Overflow's [link to the FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17) is a complete answer. But (sorry Marshall) it's not the most clear explanation. I don't know if mine is more clear, but I hope so.

---

The thing is, if `p` is a `char*` pointer, then it can be used to *modify* whatever it's pointing at.

And if you could obtain a pointer `pp` that points to `p`, but with `pp` of type `char const**`, then you could use `pp` to assign to `p` the address of a `const char`.

And with that, you could then use `p` to modify the `const char`. Or, you would think you could. But that `const char` could even be in read-only memory…

In code:

```
char const        c = 'a';
char*             p = 0;
char const**      pp = &p;               // Not allowed. :-)

*pp = &c;        // p now points to c.
*p = 'b';        // Uh oh.
```

---

As a practical solution to your code that does not compile, …

```
#include <iostream>

void print(const char** thing) {
    std::cout << thing[0] << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    print(argv);    // Dang, doesn't compile!
}
```

just do …

```
#include <iostream>

void print( char const* const* thing )
{
    std::cout << thing[0] << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    print( argv );    // OK. :-)
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Since this thread is linked as duplicates from both C and C++ posts: note that the final trick does not work in C. (There's no good reason for it to not work in C, it's probably just an oversight by the standards committee).

Comment: @MattMcNabb just *added* the C tag. This answer was fine and complete when I wrote it. It doesn't work for C, it doesn't work for Pascal, it doesn't work for Haskell, or any other language one adds tags for.

Answer (score 3):

Note, that although

```
void dosmth(const char** thing);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  dosmth(argv);
```

is forbidden, you can and should do

```
void dosmth(const char* const* thing);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  dosmth(argv);
```

Which is probably what you wanted anyway. The point here is that `thing` now refers to a `const char*` array which is itself immutable and which referenced values `char` are themselves immutable.
So, for a "*look at it, but do not change it*" scenario, `const char* const*` is the type to use.

Note: I used the more common (but in my opinion inferior) standard of trying to write the `const` modifier as left as possible. Personally, I recommend writing `char const* const*` instead of `const char* const*` as it is hugely more concise that way.

Comment: I also thought this should work as well, but gcc wants the first const not to be there. Particularly: `const char* const* thing` yields an error, but `char* const* thing` does not.

Comment: So it works for C++ but doesn't for C, so I posted new question for that because I can't find any answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319842/why-c-doesnt-allow-implicit-conversion-from-char-to-const-char-const-and

Answer (score 2):

Because it might allow us to modify a constant value. Read here to understand why: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html