# Explain: Converting 'char **' to 'const char **', Conversion loses qualifiers

Tags: c++, casting, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implicit cast from char** to const char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016098/implicit-cast-from-char-to-const-char)

Given the following code:

```
void foo( const char ** buffer );

void bar() 
{
    char * buffer;
    foo( &buffer );
}
```

Why is it that if the `foo()` function has a `const char *` parameter the compiler doesn't complain when passing in a `char *` variable into it? But when using `char **`, it cannot convert it to `const char **`? Does the compiler add any `const` qualifiers in the former case?

I've read section 4.4 of the C++ standard and it just confused me further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you cannot implicitly convert from a `T **` to a `const T **`, because the compiler can no longer guarantee that the const-ness won't be violated.

Consider the following code (borrowed from the C FAQ question on exactly this topic: [*Why can't I pass a `char **` to a function which expects a `const char **`?*](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)):

```
const char c = 'x';
char *p1;
const char **p2 = &p1;  // 3
*p2 = &c;
*p1 = 'X';              // 5
```

If the compiler allowed line 3, then line 5 would end up writing to a `const` object.

Comment: How would you modify the above code to compile properly?

Comment: @MarkP, `foo( const_cast<const char **>(&buffer) );` should work. And it's strange as for me, but standard allows `const_cast` to convert between types with different cv-qualification in any direction. So you can either remove `const` qualification by it or add, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
char const someText[] = "abcd";

void
foo( char const** buffer )
{
    *buffer = someText;
}

void
bar()
{
    char* buffer;
    foo( &buffer );
    *buffer = 'x';
}
```

If this were legal, it would be possible to modify a const object
without an intervening `const_cast`.  The conversion is forbidden
because it violates const-ness.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confusing the level of indirection the const applies to.

A `char**` can be described as `pointer to a pointer to a character` whereas a `const char**` can be described as `pointer to a pointer to a constant character`.

So when we write this differently, we have `pointer to A` (where `A = pointer to character`) and we have `pointer to B` (where `B = pointer to a constant character`).

Clearly now (I hope) A and B are distinct types, as such a pointer to A can not be assigned toa  a pointer to B (and vice versa).