# How to declare a pointer to pointer to constant in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to write a function to parse command line arguments. This is the function declaration:

```
void parse(int, char const **);
```

Just in case, I have also tried `(const char)**`, `const char **`, and `cchar **` using a `typedef const char cchar`. However, all of these (as expected, since they should all be identical) result in an error if I pass a `char **` into the function, as in:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    parse(argc, argv);
```

The error I get from GNU's compiler is `error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**'` and the one from Clang is `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char **' to 'const char **' for 2nd argument`.

I have seen such solutions suggested as declaring a pointer to a const pointer to char (`const char * const *`), but I don't want either pointer to be const because I want to be able to modify the pointer so I can iterate over an argument using `for(; **argv; ++*argv)`. How can I declare a "non-const pointer to non-const pointer to const char"?

Comment: C is not the same as C++; you need to choose a language. And you could try things like `char*const*`; however `main` wants to be declared `int main(int argc, char**argv);`

Comment: I was under the impression that all clean (no warnings) C code was valid C++ code. I'm writing this for a C++ program and using a C++ compiler, but shouldn't a C solution work just as well?

Comment: In your case only data is `const`.  The pointer is still mutable.  You can cast it to `const` using `parse(argc, const_cast<char const **>(argv));`.

Comment: [Implicit conversion from char** to const char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016098/implicit-conversion-from-char-to-const-char)

Comment: "I was under the impression that all clean (no warnings) C code was valid C++ code."-- Well, no. For example, there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C, but this would not compile in C++.

Comment: [Why C doesn't allow implicit conversion from char ** to const char *const *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35319842/841108)

Comment: ^ also, the same code can be correct in C and correct in C++ but do different things in each.  (Associativity of the conditional operator is one example that comes to mind)

Comment: "I was under the impression that all clean (no warnings) C code was valid C++ code" - That's very wrong. Identical syntax does not mean the semantics are the same!. Try `static const int i = 10; static int a[i];`! Or `auto i = 10;` in a block!

Comment: Or try out a variable-length array on your C++ compiler.  Standard C and standard C++ have a common ancestor in K&R C, and they have a common subset large enough to program in, but each has features the other lacks.  As people who come around here seem never to get tired of hearing, the two are separate languages.

Comment: *"I was under the impression that all clean (no warnings) C code was valid C++ code."* Explain `int main(void) { char *fubar = (void *)0; }`... The languages differ in numerous ways! Either you *can use* a C compiler to compile your C code, which means you probably want the `[c]` tag, or you *need* a C++ compiler to compile your C++ code, which means you probably want the `[c++]` tag. **Don't try to restrict yourself to a common subset; that'd be like willfully sleeping on the footpath of a dark, vomit-soaked alley between a free hotel and a homeless shelter.** It's just unnecessary and silly.

Comment: Following on from that, you almost certainly should *never* use *both* tags! That's actually what we call "tag spamming" here; it's a nuisance because those who have expertise in C might not have expertise in C++ and vice-versa, so you almost certainly won't get a *single* answer that you can *reasonably* accept. The answer you've accepted is `[c++]`, as are the error messages. I'm removing the `[c]` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest signature that prevents modification of the arguments whilst allowing any other `const` combination to call the function is this:

```
parse(int argc, char const* const* argv);
```

That means that `argv` is a *pointer* to a `const` *pointer* to a `const char`

You can happily iterate over the parameters like this:

```
for(auto arg = argv + 1; *arg; ++arg)
{
    if(!std::strcmp(*arg, "--help"))
        return print_help();
    else if(!std::strcmp(*arg, "-v") || !std::strcmp(*arg, "--verbose"))
        verbose_flag = true;
    // ... etc...
}
```

Notice there is no need to accept the variable `int argc` because the array of character arrays is *null terminated*.

So I normally use this:

```
struct config
{
    // program options and switches
};

config parse_commandline(char const* const* argv);
```

Comment: Is argv guaranteed to be NULL terminated? I was unaware of that fact. In that case, why is argc even required as a parameter?

Comment: @DeadBeetle Yes, that is in the standard.

Answer (score 7):

The function should be declared as:

```
void parse(int, char const * const *);
```

In C++, `char **` can implicitly add `const` at all pointer depths, so you can call it as `parse(argc, argv)`.

In C, `const` can only be added at the first pointer depth  (this is a design defect in the language). [Here is a dedicated thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35319842/841108).  So you have to call the function as:  `parse(argc,  (char const * const *)argv);` unfortunately.